# Source attribute of Silverlight MultiScaleImage

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, deepzoom

I learned we should assgin a .bin file to the Source attribute of Siverlight MultiScaleImage. For example, I learned from here (refers to code sample in section Anonymous Methods for Events),

http://www.soulsolutions.com.au/Blog/tabid/73/EntryId/410/Silverlight-Deep-Zoom-Sample-Code-Part-2.aspx

But I have tried using export function of Deep Zoom Composor will never generate .bin file. Here are my screen snapshots. Any ideas what is wrong?

(I am using VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + C#.)

[image: Blend Properties]

[image: Folder Contents]

Answer (score 6):

The MultiScaleImage control's Source property can be set in a couple different ways.  If you're setting it in XAML, you can point to the dzc_output.xml file (located in the GeneratedImages folder) directly like so:

```
<MultiScaleImage x:Name="Foo" Source="/GeneratedImages/dzc_output.xml" />
```

You can also set it in code, you you need to take the extra step of assigning it as a DeepZoomImageTileSource:

```
Foo.Source = new DeepZoomImageTileSource(
             new Uri("/GeneratedImages/dzc_output.xml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the GeneratedImages folder is an xml file called dzc_output.xml that should be the new end-point for a MultiScaleImage.

With the new versions of DeepZoomComposer, the bin file format has been replaced with this new xml file.